# Disable Ding sound in c# on form closing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an annoying issue. While a fellow stacker provided a working solution to a similar issue, i still can't get it to work in a particular instance.

i have a search form.

i open it with CTRL + F. In order to prevent the *annoying DING sound* i put

```
e.Handled = true;
e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

in the relevant handler. Works like a charm. On the second form, on the other hand

```
    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Escape) return;
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        Close();
    }
```

Still makes the Ding before closing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After i finished this question, i changed the handler.

The same code, but on **key down**.

No more dinging!